The mysterious Win+End shortcut - is it some undocumented black magic?
I am using Windows 10 and Win+End toggles gray screen.
I think if you also use Windows 10, you can
reproduce that.
However, when I look it up in the Internet, I fail to
find any documents about that. Even my AI assistant
has no knowledge of that.
Do you know where this is shortcut is documented?
Thank you!

Does nothing on my Windows 11 system. Perhaps it is a program you have installed?

Not listed in Microsoft's list of Keyboard shortcuts that apply to Windows 10 and 11 either https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec

@Mokubai Thank you! Yes, that's the exact document I read, making me so surprising that I can't find that. So it not work in Windows 11.. but a Windows 10 device of my coworker also could reproduce that, making me believe that it a system shortcut.

An answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1428744/windows-10-is-grayscale-and-color-filters-are-off suggests it might be f.lux software. Otherwise this page suggests there might be some "colour filter" which I guess might depend on your graphics drivers? Definitely doesn't work on my Nvidia system.

@Mokubai Ahhh it could be flux!!! I have installed that. Will you turn your comment to an answer so I can accept that? Thank a lot! I was too puzzled for that :)

Posted an answer, also found out why the built-in colour filter doesn't work for me... you have to actually enable the hotkey first. I've put that in my answer as well in case future visitors stumble this way, at least then they have a couple of options as to what might be doing it.

@Mokubai I got it :) Thank you again!

There are a couple of tools that can cause the screen to be grayscale.
The most likely one in your case seems to be f.lux which has a grayscale mode activated by Win+End.
According to the f.lux changelog in version 4.84 they added a grayscale mode

version 4.84: Grayscale mode, distraction-free reading
November 2018
This new version of f.lux has a grayscale mode and new key to turn it on: Windows + End.

The other option is the Windows Accessibility Colour Filter tool which can help with colour blindness or other visial impariments, but you have to specifically enable the hotkey first.
Per Microsoft: Use color filters in Windows

Select Start  > Settings  > Ease of Access > Color filters.
Switch on the toggle under Turn on color filters.
Then, select a color filter from the menu. Try each filter to see which one suits you best.

In that screen is an option to turn on a hotkey to make the screen grayscale, but by default it is off.

The hotkey is Win+Ctrl+C and does not seem to match your hotkey, so I'd say that f.lux is more likely in your case. I'd also have thought you would remember enabling that option.
